WordPress site sometimes displays as blank page on Firefox, works fine on Chrome
I have this website https://www.araspowersystems.com/ that sometimes displays as a blank page when I open it in Firefox (129.0.1). Inner pages also sometimes display as blank page. It never happens in Chrome (127.0.6533.120).
As far as I checked, it’s not caused by a plugin. But I’m using Softwerk theme and it feels like something about that is causing this, but I just couldn’t figure out what.
Any ideas what might be the cause?
Thanks!

Looks like there's an issue with the theme/framework, more specifically the page transitions.
If you apply this CSS, it will disable the loading transitions, but will ensure the page loads in Firefox.
.qodef-smooth-transition-loader{
    display: none;
}

